# Firefox 39.0: Searchbox won't disappear

Tags: firefox

Under Ubuntu the searchbox (insite-search) won't disappear. I've been told it does under windows. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Which search box do you mean?

Comment: The intext-search at the bottom of the browser.

Comment: I have finished my answer, sorry for the wrong URL, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a workaround. Simply click the close button on the right hand side in the search bar.

If you need an auto hide, install [Findbar autohide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-autohide/)

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin won't work.

Comment: I have changed my answer. This addon should work. If not, give me a comment. I will delete my answer.

Comment: It does, but only if I switch to another tab. Thanks anyway.